# NSArray from NSCharacterSet

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

Currently I am able to make array of Alphabets like below

```
[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];
```

Knowing that is available over

```
[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]
```

How to make an array out of it?

Comment: Why you need this. Or just for fun? If you can tell why you need it in array then it would be good.

Comment: have you tried using ascii values?

Comment: The uppercaseLetterCharacterSet contains a lot more than just A...Z.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following code creates an array containing all characters of a given character set. It works also for characters outside of the "basic multilingual plane" (characters > U+FFFF, e.g. U+10400 DESERET CAPITAL LETTER LONG I).

```
NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int plane = 0; plane <= 16; plane++) {
    if ([charset hasMemberInPlane:plane]) {
        UTF32Char c;
        for (c = plane << 16; c < (plane+1) << 16; c++) {
            if ([charset longCharacterIsMember:c]) {
                UTF32Char c1 = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(c); // To make it byte-order safe
                NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&c1 length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
                [array addObject:s];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` this gives an array of 1467 elements. But note that characters > U+FFFF are stored as UTF-16 surrogate pair in `NSString`, so for example U+10400 actually is stored in `NSString` as 2 characters "\uD801\uDC00".

**Swift 2** code can be found in other answers to this question.
Here is a **Swift 3** version, written as an extension method:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func allCharacters() -> [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let charset = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters
let chars = charset.allCharacters()
print(chars.count) // 1521
print(chars) // ["A", "B", "C", ... "]
```

(Note that some characters may not be present in the font used to
display the result.)

Comment: Thanks @Martin R I was having trouble with contains (unicodeScalar) bit. this is awesome :)

Comment: @MartinR I know that the question is about NSArray but I think you should post one for converting `CharacterSet` into a `Set<Character>` as well. It looks to me that it is around 10x faster to generate a set of characters instead of an array. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I will test in a real project as well to make sure but seems much faster when using a playground

Comment: @MartinR also if the order doesn't matter creating an array from the set seems the best choice.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Cannot confirm: `CharacterSet.letters.allCharacters()` takes approx 0.0064 seconds on my computer, that set has 127391 elements. With a set as result type, the time is 0.072 seconds. And that is what I would expect: appending to an array is faster than inserting into a set. – Tested with Release configuration in a compiled Xcode project.

Comment: @MartinR Thats crazy. Do you have any idea why it takes so long in a playground?

Comment: @LeoDabus: I do not know the details, but it is known that Playgrounds are sloooow. The code is not compiled with optimization (AFAIK) and executed in a special way, so that all intermediate results can be displayed in the results bar. I cannot tell why using a set makes it faster in a Playground.

Comment: @MartinR OK thanks

Answer (score 20):

Inspired by [Satachito answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51200984/1033581), here is a performant way to make an Array from CharacterSet using `bitmapRepresentation`:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func characters() -> [Character] {
        // A Unicode scalar is any Unicode code point in the range U+0000 to U+D7FF inclusive or U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive.
        return codePoints().compactMap { UnicodeScalar($0) }.map { Character($0) }
    }
    
    func codePoints() -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        var plane = 0
        // following documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1417719-bitmaprepresentation
        for (i, w) in bitmapRepresentation.enumerated() {
            let k = i % 0x2001
            if k == 0x2000 {
                // plane index byte
                plane = Int(w) << 13
                continue
            }
            let base = (plane + k) << 3
            for j in 0 ..< 8 where w & 1 << j != 0 {
                result.append(base + j)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

#### Example for uppercaseLetters

```
let charset = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters
let chars = charset.characters()
print(chars.count) // 1733
print(chars) // ["A", "B", "C", ... "]
```

#### Example for discontinuous planes

```
let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")
let codePoints = charset.codePoints()
print(codePoints) // [120488, 837521]
```

#### Performances

Very good depending on the data/usage: this solution built in release with [`bitmapRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779849-bitmaprepresentation) seems 2 to 10 times faster than Martin R's solution with [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/2908835-contains) or Oliver Atkinson's solution with [`longCharacterIsMember`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1409757-longcharacterismember).

Be sure to compare depending on your own needs: performances are best compared in a non-debug build; so avoid comparing performances in a Playground.

Comment: Sorry to inform you that Martin R answer is much faster than this approach which is about 30-35% slower.

Comment: @LeoDabus Maybe it depends on the data. I'll edit to be more neutral regarding performances.

Comment: @Cœur: I can confirm that your function is significantly faster than mine in a compiled command line project in Release mode, about twice as fast for `CharacterSet.letters.characters()`.

Answer (score 10):

Since characters have a limited, finite (and not too wide) range, you can just test which characters are members of a given character set (brute force):

```
// this doesn't seem to be available
#define UNICHAR_MAX (1ull << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unichar)))

NSData *data = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] bitmapRepresentation];
uint8_t *ptr = [data bytes];
NSMutableArray *allCharsInSet = [NSMutableArray array];
// following from Apple's sample code
for (unichar i = 0; i < UNICHAR_MAX; i++) {
    if (ptr[i >> 3] & (1u << (i & 7))) {
        [allCharsInSet addObject:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&i length:1]];
    }
}
```

Remark: Due to the size of a unichar and the structure of the additional segments in bitmapRepresentation, this solution only works for characters <= 0xFFFF and is not suitable for higher planes.

Comment: oooppppssssss. To understand this code, we need 50K+ reputations. People will get scared by this code.

Comment: @H2CO3, I thought i am just not knowing an existence of a method to call on NSCharacterSet or NSString to do this job with a one line statement. Looks like it is truly not exists. Good to see the possibility from your response. Thanks.

Comment: Remark: This works only for characters <= 0xFFFF. The `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` contains 1467 characters, this method gives only the first 871 characters.

Comment: @MartinR Right, at least as long as `unichar` is two <s>bytes</s> octets long (which it is on iOS and OS X).

Comment: @H2CO3: `NSCharacterSet` works also with characters outside the BMP, even if `NSString` uses `unichar` internally.

Comment: Personally I think that the OP doesn't even know what's he' asking because getting a list of all the `Lu` and `Lt` characters doesn't have a real use.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, that's quite possible. But anyways, he got what he asked for :) Better be technically correct than make wrong assumptions.

Comment: Can't you use `[charSet characterIsMember:]` to check if `unichar` is in the set?

Comment: Needs a lot of memory! My device runs out of memory!

Answer (score 4):

I created a Swift (v2.1) version of Martin R's algorithm:

```
let charset = NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet();

for var plane : UInt8 in 0...16 {
    if charset.hasMemberInPlane( plane ) {
        var c : UTF32Char;

        for var c : UInt32 = UInt32( plane ) << 16; c < (UInt32(plane)+1) << 16; c++ {
            if charset.longCharacterIsMember(c) {
                var c1 = c.littleEndian // To make it byte-order safe
                let s = NSString(bytes: &c1, length: 4, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding);
                NSLog("Char: \(s)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `c1` is unlikely to work as `let` because of in-out `&`, should probably be `var`

Comment: You're right, I fixed it. But I was sure I had tested this before... Well, anyway, it's correct as of Swift 2.1.1, just tested it (`Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)`)

Comment: Now that explains it! How could I not see that? Well, thanks for pointing it out @DesmondHume :)

Comment: @felipou: I apologize for the confusion. I wanted to add the (Swift equivalent of) OSSwapHostToLittleInt32 and then made some errors. Everything should be correct now.

Comment: No problem @MartinR, I understand, it's much better this way. Thanks for the contribution :)

Comment: longCharacterIsMember appears to be gone for Swift 3

Comment: Nevermind, just use `(characterSet as NSCharacterSet).longCharacterIsMember(c)` in Swift 3 (Xcode 8 Beta 6)

Answer (score 2):

This is done using a little more of swift for swift.

```
let characters = NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet()
var array      = [String]()

for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where characters.hasMemberInPlane(plane) {

  for character: UTF32Char in UInt32(plane) << 16..<(UInt32(plane) + 1) << 16 where characters.longCharacterIsMember(character) {

    var endian = character.littleEndian
    let string = NSString(bytes: &endian, length: 4, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding) as! String

    array.append(string)

  }

}

print(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found Martin R's solution to be too slow for my purposes, so I solved it another way using `CharacterSet`'s `bitmapRepresentation` property.

This is significantly faster according to my benchmarks:

```
var ranges = [CountableClosedRange<UInt32>]()
let bitmap: Data = characterSet.bitmapRepresentation
var first: UInt32?, last: UInt32?
var plane = 0, nextPlane = 8192
for (j, byte) in bitmap.enumerated() where byte != 0 {
    if j == nextPlane {
        plane += 1
        nextPlane += 8193
        continue
    }
    for i in 0 ..< 8 where byte & 1 << i != 0 {
        let codePoint = UInt32(j - plane) * 8 + UInt32(i)
        if let _last = last, codePoint == _last + 1 {
            last = codePoint
        } else {
            if let first = first, let last = last {
                ranges.append(first ... last)
            }
            first = codePoint
            last = codePoint
        }
    }
}
if let first = first, let last = last {
    ranges.append(first ... last)
}
return ranges
```

This solution returns an array of codePoint ranges, but you can easily adapt it to return individual characters or strings, etc.

Comment: Actually, there is a significant error in your algorithm: it will not support `CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")` because you do not read the value of the plane index byte (you wrongly assumed they were continous). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133647/1033581 for how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not; this is not the purpose of a character set. A `NSCharacterSet` is a possibly-infinite set of characters, possibly in not-yet-invented code points. All you want to know is "Is this character or collection of characters in this set?", and to that end it is useful.

Imagine this Swift code:

```swift
let asciiCodepoints = Unicode.Scalar(0x00)...Unicode.Scalar(0x7F)
let asciiCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: asciiCodepoints)
let nonAsciiCharacterSet = asciiCharacterSet.inverted
```

Which is analogous to this Objective-C code:

```objc
NSRange asciiCodepoints = NSMakeRange(0x00, 0x7F);
NSCharacterSet * asciiCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:asciiCodepoints];
NSCharacterSet * nonAsciiCharacterSet = asciiCharacterSet.invertedSet;
```

It's easy to say "loop over all the characters in `asciiCharacterSet`"; that would just loop over all characters from `U+0000` through `U+007F`. But what does it mean to loop over all the characters in `nonAsciiCharacterSet`? Do you start at `U+0080`? Who's to say there won't be negative codepoints in the future? Where do you end? Do you skip non-printable characters? What about extended grapheme clusters? Since it's a set (where order doesn't matter), can your code handle out-of-order codepoints in this loop?

These are questions you don't want to answer here; functionally `nonAsciiCharacterSet` is infinite, and all you want to use it for is to tell if any given character lies outside the set of ASCII characters.

---

The question you should really be asking yourself is: **"What do I want to accomplish with this array of capital letters?"** If (and likely only if) you really need to iterate over it in order, putting the ones you care about into an `Array` or `String` (perhaps one read in from a resource file) is probably the best way. If you want to check to see if a character is part of the set of uppercase letters, then **you don't care about order or even how many characters are in the set**, and should use `CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(foo)` (in Objective-C: `[NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet contains: foo]`).

Think, too, about non-latin characters. `CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters` covers Unicode General Categories [Lu](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm) and [Lt](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm), which contain `A` through `Z` and also things like `ǅ`, , and `Խ`. You don't want to have to think about this. You definitely don't want to issue an update to your app when the Unicode Consortium adds new characters to this list. **If what you want to do is decide whether something is upper-case, don't bother hard-coding anything.**

Comment: A CharacterSet, by its struct definition, is finite: it has at most 17 planes of 8192 endpoints.

Comment: @Cœur has it always been like that? Will it always be like that? What if an 18th plane is needed? Can you provide official documentation promising all this?

Answer (score 0):

For just A-Z of the Latin alphabet (nothing with Greek, or diacritical marks, or other things that were not what the guy asked for):

```
for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where characters.hasMemberInPlane(plane) {
    i = 0
    for character: UTF32Char in UInt32(plane) << 16...(UInt32(plane) + 1) << 16 where characters.longCharacterIsMember(character) {
        var endian = character.littleEndian
        let string = NSString(bytes: &endian, length: 4, encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding) as! String
        array.append(string)
        if(array.count == 26) {
            break
        }
    }
    if(array.count == 26) {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know there is going to be 26 characters, then you're not working with an arbitrary character set, which means you can optimize it in speed and in length with just `return ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can of course create sets of characters and alphabets  using `CharacterSet` like this:

```
var smallEmojiCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:  Unicode.Scalar("")...Unicode.Scalar(""))
```

The problem is that `CharacterSet` is NOT a `Set` (though it conforms to `SetAlgebra`), it is rather a unicode character set . This causes the problem of getting a sequence of all it's characters, to convert it to `Array`, `Set` or a `String`. I [have found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473051/converting-a-characterset-to-a-string-or-to-an-array-or-set-of-characters), but a better one exists. 
Actually, what you want is to stride from character to character, to have a range  "a"..."z".
It is not hard to do at the scalar level. At `Character` level there are more caveats to consider.

```
extension Unicode.Scalar: Strideable {
    public typealias Stride = Int

    public func distance(to other: Unicode.Scalar) -> Int {
        return Int(other.value) - Int(self.value)
    }

    public func advanced(by n: Int) -> Unicode.Scalar {
        return Unicode.Scalar(UInt32(Int(value) + n))!
    }
}


let alphabetScalarRange = (Unicode.Scalar("a")...Unicode.Scalar("z"))// ClosedRange<Unicode.Scalar>

let alphabetCharactersArr = Array(alphabetScalarRange.map(Character.init)) // Array of Characters from range
let alphabetStringsArr = Array(alphabetScalarRange.map(String.init)) // Array of Strings from range
let alphabetString = alphabetStringsArr.joined() // String (collection of characters) from range
// or simply
let uppercasedAlphabetString =  (("A" as Unicode.Scalar)..."Z").reduce("") { (r, us) -> String in
    r + String(us)
}
```

If you think making an extension is an overkill

```
let alphabetScalarValueRange = (Unicode.Scalar("a").value...Unicode.Scalar("z").value)
let alphabetStringsArr2 = Array(alphabetScalarValueRange.compactMap{ Unicode.Scalar($0)?.escaped(asASCII: false) })
let alphabetString2 = alphabetScalarValueRange.compactMap({ Unicode.Scalar($0)?.escaped(asASCII: false) }).joined(separator: ", ")
```

But be careful: Characters can consist of several scalars.