# How to implement a remove_if in swift (removing punctuations from array)?

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming

**Problem**

Suppose I have an array of strings.

*Using only **functional programming** (map, reduce, etc...), I want to create a new array which doesn't have any punctuation.*

Assume that there are no embedded punctuation marks (i.e. they will be by themselves).

```
let test_arr = [ "This", "is", "a", "test", ";", "try", "it", "." ]
let punc = [ "!":true, ".":true, "?":true, ";":true ]
let new_arr = test_arr.remove_if { punc[ $0 ]? != nil }  // how to implement?
```

Maybe something like this already exists?  I had no luck googling in the Apple docs.

Comment: I don't think is supported natively. Perhaps you could subclass NSArray to implement something like this.

Comment: @68cherries `extension` is the probably the way to go, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the problem that `map` is n to n and `reduce` is n to 1, but what I need is n to m.  I could use a loop obviously, but trying to avoid it...

Comment: if you use map it will actually loop also

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus the end-result is obviously the same, but `map` allows the compiler to potentially do parallelisation optimisations (hence, is more scalable/preferred)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use filter() coupled with checking the current element against NSCharacterSet's puncuationCharacterSet(). This should do what you want.

```
let test_arr = [ "This", "is", "a", "test", ";", "try", "it", "." ]

let charSet = NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet()
let noPuncuation = test_arr.filter { $0.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charSet, options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)?.startIndex == nil }

println(noPuncuation) // [This, is, a, test, try, it]
```

As a note, you can use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742659/716216) to get a list of all the characters in a given character set, or define your own character set like this.

```
let customCharset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "!@#")
```