# See what characters are in an NSCharacterSet

Tags: swift

When I'm trying

```
print(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

it prints

<__NSCFCharacterSet: 0x1759b900>

How do I make it more informative?

Comment: Possibly see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33917661/4573247

Answer (score 1):

You can get a representation of the character set using `bitmapRepresentation` which could be queried. Or you could do basically the same thing with a loop over all characters and using `characterIsMember:`. The output is potentially big...

There isn't really a simple option or a generic concise output to what you're asking for. It isn't a common requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772439/see-characters-in-an-nscharacterset-swift