# Why is the intersection of two non-overlapping CharacterSets non-empty?

Tags: swift, swift3

I was trying to user CharacterSet to check if a user input string contains any non decimal digit characters. I use `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` and take the intersection of that with the user input. If this intersection is empty, it presumably means the user hasn't entered valid input. Yet the intersection is not empty.

```swift
let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let letters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcd") // never prints

let intersection = digits.intersection(letters)
for c in "abcd".characters {
    if intersection.contains(UnicodeScalar(String(c))!) {
        print("contains \(c)") // never prints
    }
}

for i in 0...9 {
    if intersection.contains(UnicodeScalar(String(i))!) {
        print("contains \(i)")
    }
}

print("intersection is empty: \(intersection.isEmpty)") // prints false
```

I even tried looping over all unicode scalars to test for membership, and that doesn't print anything.

```
for i in 0x0000...0xFFFF {
    guard let c = UnicodeScalar(i) else {
        continue
    }
    if intersection.contains(c) {
        print("contains \(c)")
    }
}
```

Why is the set non empty?

**Note** Using `let digits = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890")` works as expected. I know that the `decimalDigits` contains more than just 0-9, but the intersection should still be empty.

Comment: There are several bug reports with respect to character sets at https://bugs.swift.org/.

Comment: Nice.. I just enumerated over `0x0000...0xFFFF` to see the other characters in .decimalDigits, I had no idea it was more than 0...9

Comment: @MathewS: If you are interested: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15741631/1187415) are some (Objective-C and) Swift methods to get all characters from a CharacterSet. There are 550 "digits", such as "꩓" (CHAM DIGIT THREE), "໔" (LAO DIGIT FOUR) or "" (MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE)

Comment: @MartinR thanks.. the Cham alphabet is beautiful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed the [`CharacterSet` bugs](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2503?jql=text%20~%20%22characterSet%22) and didn't see one around intersections incorrectly reporting `isEmpty` so if you have the time you should file a bug since this is a nice reproducible example.

In the mean time, you could try this to check to see if the input contains any characters from `.decimalDigits` characterSet:

```
let letterInput = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcd")
digits.isSubset(of: letterInput.inverted)
// -> true

let letterAndDigitInput = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcd 1234")
digits.isSubset(of: letterAndDigitInput.inverted)
// -> false

let digitInput = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234")
digits.isSubset(of: digitInput.inverted)
// -> false
```