# Strange String.unicodeScalars and CharacterSet behaviour

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a Swift 3 `CharacterSet` to filter characters out of a `String` but I'm getting stuck very early on. A CharacterSet has a method called `contains`

> > func contains(_ member: UnicodeScalar) -> Bool
> >     Test for membership of a particular UnicodeScalar in the CharacterSet.

But testing this doesn't produce the expected behaviour.

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet.capitalizedLetters

let capitalAString = "A"

if let capitalA = capitalAString.unicodeScalars.first {
    print("Capital A is \(characterSet.contains(capitalA) ? "" : "not ")in the group of capital letters")
} else {
    print("Couldn't get the first element of capitalAString's unicode scalars")
}
```

I'm getting `Capital A is not in the group of capital letters` yet I'd expect the opposite.

Many thanks.

Comment: Martin just beat me to it, but that character set does not contain the capital A you're looking for: `["ǅ", "ǈ", "ǋ", "ǲ", "ᾈ", "ᾉ", "ᾊ", "ᾋ", "ᾌ", "ᾍ", "ᾎ", "ᾏ", "ᾘ", "ᾙ", "ᾚ", "ᾛ", "ᾜ", "ᾝ", "ᾞ", "ᾟ", "ᾨ", "ᾩ", "ᾪ", "ᾫ", "ᾬ", "ᾭ", "ᾮ", "ᾯ", "ᾼ", "ῌ", "ῼ"]`

Comment: While Martin's answer was first and is correct, I think you've discovered the root of the problem — I don't even know what a capital letter is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`CharacterSet.capitalizedLetters`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscharacterset/1414409-capitalizedletters) 
returns a character set containing the characters in Unicode General Category Lt aka "Letter, titlecase". That are
"Ligatures containing uppercase followed by lowercase letters (e.g., ǅ, ǈ, ǋ, and ǲ)" (compare  [Wikipedia: Unicode character property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) or
[Unicode® Standard Annex #44 – Table 12. General_Category Values](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table)).

You can find a list here: [Unicode Characters in the 'Letter, Titlecase' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm).

You can also use the code from
[NSArray from NSCharacterset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741631/nsarray-from-nscharacterset/15742659#15742659) to dump the contents of the character
set:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func allCharacters() -> [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

let characterSet = CharacterSet.capitalizedLetters
print(characterSet.allCharacters())

// ["ǅ", "ǈ", "ǋ", "ǲ", "ᾈ", "ᾉ", "ᾊ", "ᾋ", "ᾌ", "ᾍ", "ᾎ", "ᾏ", "ᾘ", "ᾙ", "ᾚ", "ᾛ", "ᾜ", "ᾝ", "ᾞ", "ᾟ", "ᾨ", "ᾩ", "ᾪ", "ᾫ", "ᾬ", "ᾭ", "ᾮ", "ᾯ", "ᾼ", "ῌ", "ῼ"]
```

What you probably want is [`CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscharacterset/1417569-uppercaseletters) which

> Returns a character set containing the characters in Unicode General Category Lu and Lt.

Comment: Great answer, but that fileformat.info URL isn't working for me.