# Converting a CharacterSet to a String or to an array or Set of characters

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

`Fondation` has `CharacterSet` struct (briged to NSCharacterSet) for managing sets of characters, for example when working with `Formatter` instances. Surprisingly, CharacterSet is not a Set, although the functionality and purpose is totally the same. Unfortunately CharacterSet is not a Collection ether, so right now I have no idea how to retrieve its elements.

```
// We can initialize with String
let wrongCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted
// but how can we get the characters back ?
var chSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let chString = String(chSet) // doesn't work
let chS = Set(chSet) // doesn't work
let chArr = Array(chSet) // doesn't work
```

Comment: Why would you need to access all elements of the `CharacterSet` as a `Collection`? What problem are you trying to solve? As for the "functionality" of `CharacterSet` "being the same" as that of `Set`, that's because both conform to the `SetAlgebra` protocol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741631/nsarray-from-nscharacterset ? But as stated by Dávid Pásztor, what's your goal? You might have a "better way".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252492/strange-string-unicodescalars-and-characterset-behaviour/42252675#42252675

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor, thanks for reminding about `SetAlgebra`. I was not going to manipulate the elements using `Collection`'s methods. `CharacterSet` has everything for inserting, removing, searching and more. Just wanted to **view** it to make sure everything works as expected, maybe show it to to the user in some cases.
@Larme and @vadian actually answered my question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified the solution, found in answers pointed out by @Larme and @vadian. Both answers end up with the same [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742659). All I wanted was to look at the contents of the set. Yes, it is not a common thing to want to.
It turns out that the only way to get all the elements of `CharacterSet` is to loop through all possible unicode scalars and check if they belong to the set. Feels so strange to me in the word where we can switch between `Set`s, `Array`s and even `Dictionaries` so easy.
The reason for modification is and attempt to speed up the function. My rough experiments show that using scalars is 30% faster even if we create a string in the end.

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func allUnicodeScalars() -> [UnicodeScalar] {
        var result: [UnicodeScalar] = []
        for plane in Unicode.UTF8.CodeUnit.min...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in Unicode.UTF32.CodeUnit(plane) << 16 ..< Unicode.UTF32.CodeUnit(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(uniChar)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

// Testing and timing
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:"allUnicodeScalars()") {
print(String.UnicodeScalarView(chSet.allUnicodeScalars()))
}
// Time elapsed for allUnicodeScalars(): 1.936843991279602 s.
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:"allCharacters()") {
    print(String(chSet.allCharacters()))
}
// Time elapsed for allCharacters(): 2.9846099615097046 s.

//Timing functions (for reference):
private func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

private func timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode(operation: ()->()) -> Double {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    return Double(timeElapsed)
}
```

UPD: Yes, the question is a duplicate, and a better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133647/9480608) exists.