# How to know which CharacterSet contains a given character?

Tags: swift, unicode, nscharacterset

Is there a way to check if a character belongs to a `CharacterSet`?

I wanna know what `CharacterSet` should I use for character `-`. Do I use `symbols`?

I've checked this documentation but still no idea. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset

When removing extra whitespace at the end of a string, we do it like this:

```
let someString = " "
print("\(11111) - \(someString)".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
```

But what if I just want to remove the `-`? Or any special character such as `*`?

EDIT: I was looking for a complete set of characters per each `CharacterSet` if it's possible.

Comment: You mean [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/2908835-contains)?

Comment: That one helped. But I was thinking if there's a complete list for each CharacterSet?

Comment: CharacterSet.symbols.contains("-") returns false. I edited the question. `I was looking for a complete set of characters per each CharacterSet if it's possible`

Comment: You could create an empty character set and use the `insert(charactersIn:)` function to add the characters you need to trim.

Comment: [List of characters in an NSCharacterSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610931/list-of-characters-in-an-nscharacterset) [NSArray from NSCharacterSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741631/nsarray-from-nscharacterset)

Comment: @JoshCaswell FYI - The first link you provided is nothing more than a copy of Martin's answer from the second link you provided. That first one is now closed as a duplicate of the second.

Comment: Thanks for that @rmaddy! I did not look at them carefully enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is defined in the Unicode standard. It is referred to as Unicode General Categories. Each Unicode character is in a category.

The Unicode website provides a [complete character list](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn36/Categories.txt) showing the character's code, category, and name. You can also find a complete list of [Unicode categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) as well.

The `-` is U+2D (HYPHEN-MINUS). It is listed as being in the "Pd" (punctuation) category.

If you look at the documentation for `CharacterSet`, you will see `punctuationCharacters` which is documented as:

> Returns a character set containing the characters in Unicode General Category P*.

The "Pd" category is included in "P*" (which means any "P" category).

I also found https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category which is a third party list of each character by category. A bit more user friendly than the Unicode reference.

To summarize. If you want to know which `CharacterSet` to use for a given character, lookup the character's category using one of the charts I linked. Once you know its category, look at the documentation for `CharacterSet` to see which predefined character set applies to that category.

Comment: Ah, that last linked helped A LOT. `U+002D` is in Pd. Funny this is a new stuff for me. Meta SO says no need for thanks, but still thanks.